# Wicket: Two AjaxButtons inside separate forms issue

Tags: java, html, ajax, wicket

I want to place two separate file upload panels on page, one is for images, another for other files. Each panel contains a form with `AjaxButton` inside. First I developed the first panel, it worked as expected. But when I added another one, the second `AjaxButton` inside a form is not responding when clicked. Instead, when I click on the first button, the second one responds. What could be the reasons for that?

Here's the first panel's HTML:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="form-container-img">
        <form wicket:id="form-img">
            <img wicket:id="releaseImage" class="thumbnail" />
            <p>
                <label>Select file :</label> 
                <input wicket:id="fileUpload-img" size="40" type="file"/>
                <input wicket:id="uploadButton-img" id="uploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

And the second one:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="form-container-album">
        <form wicket:id="form-album">
            <span wicket:id="releaseName" />
            <p>
                <label>Select file :</label>
                <input wicket:id="fileUpload-album" size="40" type="file" /> 
                <input wicket:id="uploadButton-album" id="uploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

So now, when both panels are in place, clicking `uploadButton-album` does nothing but it responds by clicking `uploadButton-img`.

EDIT:

```
<wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="uploadPanelReleaseImg"></div>
        <div wicket:id="uploadPanelReleaseAlbum"></div>
</wicket:panel>
```

Comment: I don't know for sure that this is the problem but your 2nd form's button is an input type of `button` while the first one is of type `submit`. If you change the 2nd one to a `submit` does it change the behavior?

Comment: MikeB: Wikcet normally takes care about missing elements in markup (like type "submit"). @justasd: You have two separated forms on one page? No form nesting (would work with Wicket)? Can you provide more info about the page structure?

Comment: @MikeB I updated the post, changed second button's input type to "submit". It was like that initially, but I was playing around so at some stage changed "submit" to "button"

Comment: @mrak I updated the post again, provided the outer panel. No nested forms

Comment: @justasd Can you provide the Java-Code creating the buttons too?

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but id should be unique on a page, and you've used the same id attribute on both buttons.

Comment: @DonRoby That could be the case: Normally wicket will generate unique id-s but OP provided his own ids. In this case Wicket will not overwrite it.

Comment: @DonRoby That was the case. I changed the ids to be different and it works. Thank you

Comment: Great!  I'll make it an answer, so there's an answer.  And then you can accept it, and we'll both gain some points.  Not that that's a great concern to me at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html markup, the id attribute should always be unique on the page.  I'm not sure it's required by any spec, but it's generally regarded as good practice, and things tend frequently to depend on it.

If you need to control the id (because you're referencing it in JavaScript and it's easier than figuring out what id Wicket generated), you need to manage this manually.

If you simply omit the id attribute, Wicket will generate one based on the wicket id, and guarantee uniqueness on the page.

Based on the comment thread, this appears to have been the problem.